# Call functions of a dynamically imported module

Tags: python, import

I have this module (called module1.py):

```
import os
def main():
    command=os.system("dir")
    return command,"str"
```

I have dynamically imported it with this:

```
mod = __import__("modules."module1)
```

It works great. But now I want to call the function "main" of module1.

`mod.main()` does not work. Why?? How may I call the main() function of the module1 module?

Thank you very much

Comment: I very much doubt that `__import__("modules."module1)` works; that is not valid Python.

Comment: ^what he said,  In addition this method described here does work fine.  I just did something very similar yesterday

Comment: And why not use the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer using the `fromlist` argument.

```
mod = __import__("modules.%s" % (module1), fromlist=["main"])
mod.main()
```

Depending on your use case you may also want to specify locals and globals.

```
mod = __import__("modules.%s" % (module1), locals(), globals(), ["main"])
```

Comment: Very easy and perfect!! Thank you very much!